# How to return a SOME list instead of a normal list?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am trying to implement a program that takes a string and a list and returns `NONE` if it doesn't find any match and the list without the element if it does.

```
fun all_except_option ("string",["he","she","string"]) = SOME["he","she"]
```

I have managed to make it working, but without the options type and i have no idea how to make it return `SOME list` instead a normal list.

```
fun all_except_option(str,lst)=
    case lst of
         [] => []
      | x::lst' => if same_string(x,str) = false
                   then let fun append (word, list) = word::list
                        in append(x,[]) :: all_except_option(str,lst')
                        end
                   else all_except_option(str,lst')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I managed to make it working, but i still don't understand the "else case" and how is my programm handling it. Here is the working code. I would be glad if you can explain me the "else case  all_except_option(str,list') of".

```
fun all_except_option(str,list)=
    case list of
    [] => NONE
      | x::list' => if same_string(x,str)  then
            
              SOME( list')
                                  
            else case  all_except_option(str,list') of
                 NONE=>NONE
               | SOME list'=>SOME(x::list')
```

Comment: That's not correct. Why did you remove a recursion and replace it with a `SOME`? Your `NONE` case is incorrect, too. Test with `("a", ["a", "a"])` and `("a", ["b"])`.

Comment: It works fine for the ("a",["b"]), but it doesn't work for ("a", ["a", "a"]) ,which actually fine since the exercise says that the elements in the list won't be repeating.

Comment: Okay, my bad. I will be more precise next time

Answer (score 0):

> implement a program that takes a string and a list and returns `NONE` if it doesn't find any match and the list without the element if it does.
>
> ```
> all_except_option ("string",["he","she","string"]) = SOME ["he","she"]
> ```

How is `SOME []` different from `NONE`? As in, if this function returned just a list, it would be possible to say that removing occurrences of `"string"` results in no other strings: Either the list was empty already, or it contained only occurrences of `"string"`. I am not sure why `NONE` vs. `SOME []` is warranted in one case over the other.

So the better function is one that simply returns a plain list:

```
fun except (x, ys) = List.filter (fn y => x <> y)
```

When is it useful to return *'a option*?

For example when the return type does not have a way to indicate no result already:

```
fun lookup k1 [] = NONE
  | lookup k1 ((k2,v)::pairs) =
      if k1 = k2
      then SOME v
      else lookup k1 pairs
```

This function returns 0 or 1 thing. But it's also a simple function because it never aggregates results over its recursion. Recursive functions become complicated when they return composite data types like *'a option* when it needs to unpack the result of the recursion.

A good example is an `eval` function that sometimes fails:

```
datatype expr
  = Add of expr * expr
  | Sub of expr * expr
  | Mul of expr * expr
  | Div of expr * expr
  | Int of int

fun eval (Int n) = SOME n
  | eval (Add (e1, e2)) = evalHelper ( op+ ) (e1, e2)
  | eval (Sub (e1, e2)) = evalHelper ( op- ) (e1, e2)
  | eval (Mul (e1, e2)) = evalHelper ( op* ) (e1, e2)
  | eval (Div (e1, e2)) =
      case eval e1 of
           NONE => NONE
         | SOME x => case eval e2 of
                          NONE => NONE
                        | SOME 0 => NONE
                        | SOME y => SOME (x div y)

and evalHelper binop (e1, e2) =
      case eval e1 of
           NONE => NONE
         | SOME x => case eval e2 of
                          NONE => NONE
                        | SOME y => SOME (binop (x, y))
```

Here the return type is *int option*, which means that you most often return an *int*, but if you ever divide by zero, that results in "no value", so rather than raise an exception, we return `NONE`, which necessitates us to return `SOME n` when there is a result, so that the type fits in both cases.

A quick demonstration:

```
- eval (Div (Int 5, Int 2));
> val it = SOME 2 : int option
- eval (Div (Int 5, Int 0));
> val it = NONE : int option
- eval (Div (Int 2, Sub (Int 3, Int 3)));
> val it = NONE : int option
- eval (Div (Int 0, Int 1));
> val it = SOME 0 : int option
```

Here `SOME 0` actually means "the result is 0", which is not the same as "cannot divide by zero."

Comment: "All the elements were the one you looked for" (i.e. success) is different from "your element was not found" (failure). As you note yourself, a plain list can't express the difference.

Comment: Right, so I question the usefulness of being told that a list is empty because it was empty to begin with ("all the *(non-existent)* elements were the ones you looked for"). Perhaps with a less trivial search function than this one that doesn't just return a sub-list of the input. I can think of problems where *int list option* is the return type, such as the "giving back exact change" task of finding, for a given set of coins and some cashback amount, some (possibly least) amount of coins that add up to the cashback. In that case, `SOME []` signifies "there exists a solution with 0 coins."